# UiPath Structure

Tags: testing, automation, structure, uipath

Good day

I would like to know if the following is considered good programming on UiPath. I am currently busy with test automations on UiPath. My test automation is testing if a web API is working correctly.
[Uipath Automation Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8287.png)
As seen in the picture above i am opening the web API on the browser then i keep it open while testing the API with my entire test data source and after the testing is done i close the browser.

I would like to know if this is good programing or should i open and close the web browser with each test data occurrence.

Currently I am keeping the web API open for the entire testing of test data source and testing is working great but i dont know if this is considered good programming

Comment: Not sure what you try to do. An API is usually not used by a browser. What is your task?